# Make plot between multiple files for a particular Id in a specific period

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a plot to compare 4 different files. each file has ID, Date and Value. While ID's and dates remain the same the value differs in each of the files. Now i want to plot the value field for ID lets say "A" for some 7 day period in January. The result would be a a overlaying plot of four different value from the four different files. How can i go about this in python? I want to keep it as automated as possible without several manual steps. Appreciate all your help!

Example data set below 
Sample data set 1

ID Date Value 
A  01-01-18 12 
A 01-02-18 15
A 01-03-18 18
A 02-01-18 12 
B 01-01-18 11
B 01-02-18 19
C 01-01-18 15

Sample data set 2

ID Date Value 
A 01-01-18 13 
A 01-02-18 16
A 01-03-18 12
A 02-01-18 13 
B 01-01-18 16
B 01-02-18 15
C 01-01-18 13

Sample data set 3

ID Date Value 
A 01-01-18 12 
A 01-02-18 12
A 01-03-18 13
A 02-01-18 14 
B 01-01-18 15
B 01-02-18 12
C 01-01-18 13

Sample data set 4

ID Date Value 
A 01-01-18 12 
A 01-02-18 15
A 01-03-18 14
A 02-01-18 12 
B 01-01-18 11
B 01-02-18 14
C 01-01-18 13

From this sample data -lets say i am trying to plot for ID "A" between date 01-01-18 to 01-03-18 the values. So i will have a plot of 4 different lines representing the value of each of the data set.

I have been able to do this in Excel but it has involved too many manual steps and the data is 800,000 lines +, so i don't feel very confident. I am sure there is a better way to do it in python.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Questions like this one are a lot easier to help with when you provide a [mcve], or at least a small example dataset that provides enough data to demonstrate a solution.  It can take a little extra work to prep and provide good example data, but you'll find it gets you better answers, faster.  (And it's a lot more helpful for others coming to your post in the future with a similar question.)

Comment: Thanks andrew, i was trying to put a sample data in but it loses all formatting while posting. is there a way for me to post without losing the formatting? Thanks

Comment: Sure, have a look at [How do I format by code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).  In short, use backticks for inline code and indent 4 spaces per line for longer blocks.  (There are a few other methods covered in that post.)

Comment: Also, it will be appreciated by most if you can show what you've tried so far, and what hasn't worked.  Even if it's not much of a start, it will go a long way towards people feeling that they're helping you learn, rather than providing free consulting solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your data is stored in separate text files. Then you may do what you want with the following code:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

filenames = ['sample_1.txt', 'sample_2.txt', 'sample_3.txt', 'sample_4.txt']

data = list()

for filename in filenames:
    data.append(pd.read_table(filename, delimiter=' ', parse_dates=[1]))

fig = plt.figure()

for idx in range(len(filenames)):

    condition_1 = data[idx].loc[:, 'ID'] == 'A'
    condition_2 = (
        (data[idx].loc[:, 'Date'] >= '2018-01-01') &
        (data[idx].loc[:, 'Date'] <= '2018-01-03'))

    plt.plot(
        data[idx].loc[condition_1 & condition_2, 'Date'],
        data[idx].loc[condition_1 & condition_2, 'Value'], 'o--')

plt.title('Some figure')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.legend(filenames)

# X-axis formatting
days = mdates.DayLocator()
days_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
fig.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(days)
fig.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(days_fmt)
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Poolka, i haven't tried this as i am having some issues. Maybe you can help break it down for me. My data doesn't have column headers so is there a way for me to add headers like ID, date etc? or without adding header can i use something like lookup column 1 for the id then column 3 for date and column 4 for value etc. Before i plot it i'd like to extract that to another txt file. And my data also has hours column so there will be 24 data lines for each date.

Comment: @Patrick Everything you have described is possible with not that great modification - just google reference for the functions in the code. You will need `pd.read_table(..., header=None, names=*list of predefined names*)`, `mdates.HourLocator()`, `mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H')` and so on.